# Correct film crediting

Tags: film, sound, location

I worked on a film earlier this year as the on set mixer. They are busy crediting the film and there is some confusion as to what my title should be. Can anyone please provide some clarity as to what some of the correct titling is.

Answer (score 2):

Sound Mixer or Sound Recordist